# Static variable in Java compile time error, in C one time memory allocation

Tags: java, c

When initialising a static variable in C, by functionality, memory allocation takes place only once. Hence on incrementing the variable in the same function, it retains the incremented value during the next function call. However, the same test fails in Java, giving a compilation error, specifying, static cannot be used.

Tried coding in Java and C and different results obtained. C executes, while Java provides a compilation error.

C Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func()
{
    static int k=0;
    printf("%d ",++k);
}   
int main() 
 {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    func();
  return 0;
 }
```

Java Code:

```
 public class Test
  {
     public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         Test obj=new Test();
         for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
         obj.increment();
      } 
     void increment()
      {
          static int i=0;
         System.out.println(i++);
      }
 }
```

C output:

1
2
3
4
5

Java compile time error:

java: illegal start of expression

Comment: [How do I create a static local variable in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2079830)

Answer (score 3):

in Java there is no `static` local variables - the only places to put `static` keyword are:

#### field

```
public class Test {
    static Object staticField;
    // ...
```

#### method

```
public class Test {
    static Object getStaticField() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
```

#### inner class

```
public class Test {
    static class InnerTest {
       // ...
    }
    // ...
```

#### static initialization block

```
public class Test {
    static Object staticField;
    static { // this will be called before constructor
        staticField = new Object();
    // ...
```

#### import

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI; // now you can use PI without 'Math.'
```

Comment: I changed your formatting a bit because I noticed that the bullets were breaking the code blocks. Let me know if you want to roll back.

Answer (score 2):

Java and C are separate and very different languages, syntactic similarities notwithstanding.  The `static` keyword has completely different meaning  in Java from the two different meanings it has in different C contexts.

In C, `static` is either about *linkage* (related Java concept: visibility) or about *storage duration* (your case; no direct Java analog).  In Java, on the other hand, `static` is about whether a variable or method is associated with class instances or only with an overall class.  Java allows that to be specified only for class members, not for local variables.  These really aren't comparable.

Answer (score 0):

*static variable in c is much different than the static variable in java.*
     -Static variables in c have a property of preserving their value even after 
      they are out of their scope!Hence, static variables preserve their 
      previous value in their previous scope and are not initialized again in 
      the new scope,so as your answer is 1,2,3......
     -but in java.. When a variable is declared as static, then a single copy of 
      variable is created and shared among all objects at (class level). Static 
      variables are, essentially, global variables. All instances of the class 
      share the same static variable. NOTE:in java you can only declare static 
      variable in class level.

```
public class Test
{
    static int i=0;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Test obj=new Test();
         for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
         obj.increment();
    } 
    void increment()
   {
       System.out.println(i++);
   }
}
```